# u,v harmonic on D and v is the harmonic conjugate of u. $(u,v)\ne(0,0)$. prove: $\varphi=e^{-{v\over u^2+v^2}}\cos({u\over u^2+v^2})$ is harmonic on D

Tags: complex-analysis, multivariable-calculus

need help solving this question:

Given $u$ and $v$ harmonic on $D$ and $v$ is the harmonic conjugate of $u$. 
Assuming that $(u,v)\ne(0,0)$.
Lets define: $\varphi= e^{-{v\over u^2+v^2}}\cos({u\over u^2+v^2})$

Prove: $\varphi$ harmonic on - $D$.

I found the derivatives $\varphi_{xx}$ and $\varphi_{yy}$ using the chain rule $[\varphi=\varphi(u(x,y),v(x,y))]$. Using the Cauchy–Riemann equations, algebera and the fact that $\bigtriangledown^2u=\bigtriangledown^2v=0$ I got to this equation:

$\varphi_{xx}+\varphi_{yy}=(\varphi_{uu}+\varphi_{vv})[(u_x)^2+(v_x)^2]$

By defining: $f(z)=u+iv $ , which is holomorphic, we can assume that $f^{'}(z)=u_x+iv_x$ which means $|f^{'}(z)|^2=(u_x)^2+(v_x)^2$

And at last I got to this equation:

$\varphi_{xx}+\varphi_{yy}=(\varphi_{uu}+\varphi_{vv})|f^{'}(z)|^2$

Here I got stuck and I assume that I made some unnecessary transitions (like the last one).

I could always differentiate $\varphi$ as a function of $u$ and $v$ but it will be too long and seems unlikely.

I wanted to know how should I continue and if I am at the right direction.

Thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would go along another way.

Consider $$g(x,y)=e^{-i/(u+vi)},$$
we have that $g$ is analytic (by identifying $z=x+yi$) on the domain where $(u,v)$ does not vanish.

Observe that
\begin{align*}
e^{\frac{-v}{u^2+v^2}}cos
\left (\frac{u}{u^2+v^2}\right)
&=Re\left(
e^{\frac{-v}{u^2+v^2}}\times e^{\frac{-u}{u^2+v^2}i}
\right)\\
&=Re\left(
e^{-i\frac{u-vi}{u^2+v^2}}\right)\\
&=Re\left(
e^{\frac{-i}{u+vi}}\right)\\
&=Re(g(x,y)),
\end{align*}
where $Re$ means the real part, we have the desired result (since $g$ is analytic, which implies that $Re(g)$ is harmonic).

Comment: That's really a nice solution (and thank you for that), but I would still like to know where i failed or better how I should continue.